# Bypass default route for outgoing connections

Tags: sockets

I an writing a small application that needs to connect through one of multiple network interfaces on the machine. The interface is not the "default" one (the one with the default route). Is it possible to bind an outbound TCP socket directly to a specific interface?

Here is an example:

```
eth0: 192.168.1.10, gateway 192.168.1.1
eth1: 192.168.2.10, gateway 192.168.2.1
default gateway: 192.168.1.1
(both interfaces can reach the Internet through different external IPs)
```

Now, I want my application to use `eth1` to connect to an external server, even if the system is configured to use eth0 for external traffic.

(The question is probably trivial, but I just wanted to know if it is possible at all before spending time on it)

Currently, I am using Python with Twisted, but if I have to use BSD sockets then so be it.

Comment: It's rather simple to bind a socket to a specific interface (or at least a specific IP address) - the consequences are that the socket can only set up connections that can be routed to/from that IP address.. But what do you mean by "but I want to use that gateway through to the internet" ? Which gateway ?

Comment: I edited my question for clarification, please see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: The routing is done at the OS TCP/IP stack level, not at the Socket API level, so, basically, in your configuration your system doesn't know how to access Internet through eth1. You can enable multiple default gateways at the OS level (http://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/), and in that case the Socket API should use it (but I've never worked with such setup, so can't assure you)

Answer (score 0):

From: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl7_socket.htm

`SO_DONTROUTE` - Don't send via a gateway, only send to directly connected hosts. The same effect can be achieved by setting the `MSG_DONTROUTE` flag on a socket `send(2)` operation. Expects an integer boolean flag.

Comment: I know about SO_DONTROUTE, but I want to connect to a server on the Internet, not the local LAN segment.